# How to use Salesforce Field Service Mobile Flow in app AND lightning web

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I am designing a *Field Service Mobile Flow* for a Salesforce instance (release **Winter '23 Patch 17.7**) using the [Field Service Lightning](https://www.salesforce.com/products/service-cloud/field-service/) package to manage technicians with service appointments in the field. The flow will be presented to technicians in the field in the Salesforce [Field Service Mobile](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/field-service-mobile/id1414669075) (FSM) app on iOS devices.

This flow will be added as quick action on a specific object, e.g. a ServiceAppointment object. Hence it will be presented in the app to the technician to execute the flow. Additionally, quick actions are also shown in the lightning web view of the object, enabling to execute the same flow, even though it is a *Field Service Mobile Flow*.

The challenge occurs, when trying to use the Id of the calling record (here the ServiceAppointment) as input.

The FSM app provides the Id of the calling object as variable `Id`, while a flow executed from the lightning web view passes the variabled `recordId`.

How can one handle this to use the same *Field Service Mobile Flow* in the FSM app AND in web lightning view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a subflow to retrieve the origin of the call, differentiating between the two input variables, and setting an output variable `current_record_id` accordingly.

[image: FS Mobile Flow call orign ids]

---

The condition checks, wether the input variable `Id` or the input variable `recordId` is set and assigns the output variable `current_record_id` accordingly.

[image: Condition outcome for FieldService Mobile]

[image: Condition outcome for Salesforce Web]

---

You might already spot the actual challenge. The behaviour of not-provided variables is different in the FSM app, the web call and (to make it even worse) when debugging the flow.

The following table shows my checks for the different origins and the resulting outcome (which check proofs as true)

| Path | Call flow from | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FSM app (provides `Id`) | `recordId` is **null** |
| 2 | Lightning Web (provides `recordId`) | `Id` is *empty* |
| 3 | Flow designer debug (`recordId` provided) | `Id` is **null** |
| 4 | Flow designer debug (`Id` provided) | `recordId` is **null** |

hence we have to explicitly check for null OR empty for the missing variable.

---

Now you can use four *Field Service Mobile Flow* via a quick action the Field Service Mobile App, in Salesforce Lightning and in the Flow Debugger successfully.